# how select item,DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue("-").Select in wizardstep? Exception:NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, webforms

How to select item FindByValue DropDownList in **wizardstep**

Exception:

> NullReferenceException
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...

    DropDownList DropDownList2 = 
       (DropDownList)Wizard1.WizardSteps[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");

    DropDownList2.Items.FindByValue(
        DataSetLoad.Tables[1].Rows[0]["a"].ToString()).Selected = true;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...

```
DropDownList DropDownList2 = 
   (DropDownList)Wizard1.WizardSteps[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
DropDownList2.DataBind();
DropDownList2.Items.FindByValue(
    DataSetLoad.Tables[1].Rows[0]["a"].ToString()).Selected = true;

...
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If the null exception is the only reason your wizard is not working, then attach a debugger, then use the [visual studio immediate window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx) to systematically go through each of your objects to determine which one is null.

For example,  `Wizard1.WizardSteps[1].FindControl("DropDownList1")` may return null if it can not find your control.  If this is the case, then you can proceed to ask, well, why is it not finding your control.

Update:

Based on the code you provided, is there a reason you are not using the variable DropDownList1 directly? Instead of:

```
DropDownList DropDownList2 = 
   (DropDownList)Wizard1.WizardSteps[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");

DropDownList2.Items.FindByValue(
    DataSetLoad.Tables[1].Rows[0]["a"].ToString()).Selected = true;
```

Why not just use:

```
  DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(
    DataSetLoad.Tables[1].Rows[0]["a"].ToString()).Selected = true;
```

The above suggestion is based on the assumption that your original problem (the null reference) occured because your `FindControl` method was not successfully finding `DropDownList1`

Comment: Have you first determined that the null reference is caused by `DropDownList2` being null? If so, you need to provide more information on how `DropDownList1` is created.

Comment: Before we go down this path of finding reasons why `DropDownList2` might be null, have you **determined** that it **is** null?

Comment: '<asp:Wizard  ID="Wizard1" runat="server" 
        ....
        <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" runat="server" Title="1111" >
                <fieldset style="width:650px;">
                    <legend>aaa</legend>
                    <table>
                         ...'

Comment: '<tr>
                            <td class="style41">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label104" runat="server" Text="gggg:"></asp:Label></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceScienceSocietyCountery" 
                                    DataTextField="CounteryDescription" DataValueField="CounteryDescription" 
                                    Width="145px" Height="22px">
                                </asp:DropDownList>'

Comment: '<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringElection %>" 
                                    SelectCommand="SELECT 0 AS CounteryID, '-' As CounteryDescription UNION SELECT * FROM [Countery]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                            </td>
                                
                        </tr>
                        ...
                        
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
</asp:WizardStep>'

Comment: @PMD.info, you have still not answered my question.  Please also place your source code in the original question so that the code is not in fragments, and so that others may contribute.  When using [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) the naming container matters!